# Check URL is an image or not using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if url is image, so I did use `getheader`; the getheader is working on localhost but not working on hosting server. I also tried to use `getimagesize` also it's working on localhost but not working on web hosting server even my php.ini is set to

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

for get_header my code is

```
$url = "https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.411.suffix/1455654217545";

        $url_headers=get_headers($url, 1);

 if(isset($url_headers['Content-Type'])){

            $type=strtolower($url_headers['Content-Type']);

            $valid_image_type=array();
            $valid_image_type['image/png']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/jpg']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/jpeg']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/jpe']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/gif']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/tif']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/tiff']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/svg']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/ico']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/icon']='';
            $valid_image_type['image/x-icon']='';

            if(isset($valid_image_type[$type])){

                echo "Yes it's Images";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "no image";
            }
        }
```

var_dump of getheader on localhost display

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' (length=15)
  'Content-Type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'Server' => string 'Apache' (length=6)
  'X-Content-Type-Options' => string 'nosniff' (length=7)
  'X-Frame-Options' => string 'SAMEORIGIN' (length=10)
  'Content-Length' => string '38885' (length=5)
  'Cache-Control' => string 'max-age=2522004' (length=15)
  'Expires' => string 'Fri, 03 May 2019 08:55:29 GMT' (length=29)
  'Date' => string 'Thu, 04 Apr 2019 04:22:05 GMT' (length=29)
  'Connection' => string 'close' (length=5)
  'Vary' => string 'User-Agent' (length=10)
```

But var_dump on web hosting server display

```
    Array
(
    [server] => AkamaiGHost, Apache
    [content-length] => 0, 2077
    [location] => https://www.foodnetwork.com/not-available.html
    [cache-control] => max-age=0, max-age=433
    [expires] => Thu, 04 Apr 2019 05:16:02 GMT, Thu, 04 Apr 2019 05:23:15 GMT
    [date] => Thu, 04 Apr 2019 05:16:02 GMT, Thu, 04 Apr 2019 05:16:02 GMT
    [connection] => keep-alive, keep-alive
    [vary] => User-Agent, User-Agent, Accept-Encoding
    [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [access-control-allow-method] => GET
    [server-timing] => edge; dur=0, cdn-cache; desc=HIT
    [x-akamai-transformed] => 9 - 0 pmb=mRUM,3
    [access-control-allow-origin] => *
    [content-encoding] => gzip
)
```

and for getimagesize my code is

```
 if (@getimagesize($url)) {
    echo  "image exists ";
    } else {
    echo  "image does not exist ";
    }
```

also is working on localhost but not working on web host server the var_dump of @getimagesize($url) is displaying :

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Did you get proper path of image on server?

Comment: use `file_exists()` check first. To ensure that image path is correct.

Comment: Yes I did if I access image image direct on browser i see that content type is image/jpeg

Comment: Can you please turn on error reporting on server please?

Comment: I have no error is just return that the url is not image: the url of image is : https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.411.suffix/1455654217545

Comment: @vishwakarma09 : the file_exists() return false. but the url is an image and you can access image direct

Comment: There is a issue in your image URL. You are using any caching system or versioning for the image. Please remove that to check image exist or not only at that point.

Comment: At the time of checking image, image url should be : https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg

Comment: @MayankDudakiya : "You are using any caching system or versioning for the image." how to remove that.

Comment: @Bynd do not give web url like http://, instead give file system path like /var/www/html/content/... and then see what `file_exists` returns

Comment: I don't know what you have used to do that in your web application. You should find that first. And remove it. THen it will work

Comment: @vishwakarma09 but the image is on remote url.

Comment: what I don't understand is why on localhost is working but on web server is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you comment, You image url is wrong. Is should be : https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg

You should remove image caching and image versioning at the time of checking.

Best solution to check weather file is image or not

> **Solution 1**

```
if(@is_array(getimagesize($mediapath))){
    $image = true;
} else {
    $image = false;
}
```

> **Solution 2**

```
$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']);
$error = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
```

> **Solution 3**

```
 $supported_image = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png','bmp');

$src_file_name = 'https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg';

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($src_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)){
    echo "it's image";
 }
 else {
    echo 'not image';
 }
```

Comment: the 3 solution return false

Comment: I have read your comment above. Your image URL is wrong. You are adding "rend.hgtvcom.616.411.suffix/1455654217545'  this at the end of url. You should remove this at the time of checking image

Comment: Try this URL to test image exist or not : https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2016/2/16/2/Orig-Paul-Schultz_Toybox-Home-kitchen-1.jpg

Comment: I did try with the url you told me to use but I get that url not image

Comment: if you can see the difference between var_dump on localhost and web hosting server maybe you will find any error

Comment: i have changed the solution 3 please copy paste and check in your local or live

Comment: the solution 3 is working with the url you give me it return it's image. But not working with url I posted on my question. so I Think I can't use the url I did post on my question

Comment: You should find out that and remove that. If you are working on wordpress then there should be a plugin or code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should follow redirect headers (codes 30x)
2. In this case the image seems 'not available' because the redirect is to a not available page, it seems. Maybe the URL is wrong?
3. What you should also watch out for: many content providers check at least for a HTTP referrer header or they deny access to images (to make crawling a bit harder). Others check for a previously set cookie. And finally some can use some complex token-based authentication (which I will not get into). But for the first issues and also following redirects, you should use Curl: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
4. Content-type headers are very often unreliable. I would recommend using the exif image type returned by `getimagesize` in result index 2, which you seem to be calling anyway.

So to recap: use Curl to set referrer and follow redirects and maybe propagate cookies from a previous referrer page that you might browse, and once you get the content use `getimagesize` to determine type.

Comment: can you please give an example I dont understand well : So to recap: use Curl to set referrer and follow redirects and maybe propagate cookies from a previous referrer page that you might browse, and once you get the content use getimagesize to determine type.

Comment: You could check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549045/how-can-get-an-image-from-a-301-redirect-download-link-in-php or https://www.google.com/search?q=php+download+image+curl&rlz=1C1CHBF_enRO812RO812&oq=php+download+image+curl&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l3.3135j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: If you don't understand the recap, it's short from recapitulation: it's a summary of the points above, the ones numbered from 1 to 4. Maybe those can be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

@getimagesize function take much time to respond. use below code for quick respond

```
function image_urlexists($url) {

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
    
        return ($code == 200); // verifica se recebe "status OK"
    }
    $url = 'https://www.example.com/static/cs/img/pages/home/security-card-xl.png';
    if (image_urlexists($url))
     echo "valid Url of image";
    else
     echo "Not valid url image";
```